# what does mean &-> in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Trying to understand the solution to this problem but i have no idea what this symbol means &-> can someone help

```
# Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given
# stock on day i. Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may
# complete as many transactions as you like (ie, buy one and sell one share
# of the stock multiple times). However, you may not engage in multiple
# transactions at the same time (ie, you must sell the stock before you buy
# again).


def max_profit(prices)
  prices.each_cons(2).map(&->(p1, p2){ [p2 - p1, 0].max }).reduce(0, &:+)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's two operators together. `->` creates a lambda, and `&` passes it as a block.

Comment: Can you also say that it is an anonymous function ?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Yes, The lambda's defining an anonymous function

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 operators involved:

- `->` creates a `lambda`
- `&` will take a `Proc` (or `lambda`) and pass it as block

The same code could be written as:

```
prices.each_cons(2).map { |p1, p2| [p2 - p1, 0].max }.reduce(0, &:+)
```